# Non Nobis Domine - Sed nomini or nomine

Tags: grammar-identification

> Non nobis Domine, Domine
> Non nobis Domine
> Sed nomini, Sed nomini
> Tuo da gloriam

Referring to the third line in Non Nobis Domine, I have seen this phrase written both 'Sed nomine' and 'Sed nomini'. In the Henry V film based on Shakespeare's play, they seem to sing, 'nomine.' However, I think it requires the dative and would therefore be 'Sed nomini.'

If this is not the correct logic, or if my conclusion is incorrect, please let me know.

Answer (score 9):

Your logic is correct, it is the dative. Grammatically, you could certainly say *nomine tuo da gloriam* (give glory in your name, perhaps), but it hardly fits in context.

This is a direct quote from [the Vulgate bible, Ps. 113:9](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Ps%20113%3A9&version=VULGATE) (a.k.a. Psalm 115):

> Non nobis, Domine, non nobis, sed nomini tuo da gloriam.

There is, by the way, a long [Wikipedia entry on this verse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_nobis). It's pretty unequivocal that it should be *nomini*.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply and reference to Wikipedia.  This is great.